# Add icon to a panel in Sencha

Tags: icons, extjs

I am new to sencha. I am trying to add an icon to a panel, but my code doesn't work.

```
   Ext.define('components.ImagePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',    
    initialize: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        var image = {
            xtype: "image",
            src: 'icon.png',
            width:100,
            height:100
                }, 
            scope: this
        };
 this.add([image]);
});
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, didn't even know that there was an image xtype.

Anyway...

To use an xtype, you need to create it using `Ext.widget();`

So your code should look something like this:

```
Ext.define('components.ImagePanel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',    
initialize: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    var image = Ext.widget('image',{
        xtype: "image",
        src: 'icon.png',
        width:100,
        height:100
    });
    this.add([image]);
};
});
```